# Can this property be characterized by some algebraic relations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, let $H$ be its subgroup and let $T$ be the unit circle. Let $b:G\times G\to T$. How can we characterize the fact that there is $a:G\to T$, such that $a(gh)=a(g)a(h)$, for any $g\in G, h\in H$ and such that $b(f,g)=\frac{a(f)a(g)}{a(fg)}$, for any $f,g\in G$?

Comment: If $a(gh) = a(g)a(h)$, isn't $b(f, g)$ identically $1$? Is $T$ the group of complex numbers with modulus $1$, under multiplication?

Comment: @pjs36: the equality only holds when $h\in H$. Yes $T$ is the group that you described.